# How can I create an animated e-mail / SMS notification on an Android phone?

Tags: android, email, events, notifications, sms

Is there any way to create a notification when a new e-mail arrives in my Android inbox? I would like to show an animation when I receive a new e-mail or SMS - would this be possible without writing my own e-mail client?

I'd also like to be able to customize the notifications based on who the sender is, the subject line, etc - basically, the same sort of criteria I can use to filter a message using any of the big existing clients.

Has anyone tried this before? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to put Android in the title and/or the body of the question.

Comment: Whew! Heaven forbid we try to be a bit friendly around here...

Comment: @Andy: sorry about that - i'd re-written the original at roughly the same time you were, and submitted somewhat later, losing your changes. So i re-edited to restore yours, with a couple of minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there aren't any documented email intent triggers for either of the default email programs (email and gmail). Unfortunately I think your only option would be to write your own email client (and maybe file a bug report/feature request) or dig up a non-standard email client that DOES trigger intents on incoming email.

The [Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) has information on all of the built-in intents and intent triggers and openintents.org [maintains a table](http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable) of many (but not all) 3rd party intents.

Comment: K Without writing the email client not able to do wrote the appl i need write app as standalone app.......
plz guide regarding that there is no option for fing how to react a incoming email......like SMS Reciever

Comment: As far as I can tell it isn't currently possible w/o writing at least part of an email client.

Answer (score -1):

For notification of incomming sms, this should be possible to do with AT UR codes (specifically AT+CNMA), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240131/1240738#1240738) for more details. This is provided that you have access to a modem serial port. I know too little about Android, but the phone part is normally abstracted though the RIL (right?), but is it still possible to access the modem part?